# Pivot_longer from multiple columns pairwise

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

There is a dataset like this

```
df <- data.frame(
  Pseudonym = c("aa", "bb"),
  KE_date_1 = c("2022-04-01", "2022-04-03"),
  KE_content_2 = c("high pot", "high pot"),
  KE_date_3 = c("2022-08-01", "2022-08-04"),
  KE_content_4 = c("high pot return", "high pot return")
)
```

```
Pseudonym | KE_date_1 |   KE_content_2| KE_date_3  |  KE_content_4
--------------------------------------------------------------------
aa        | 2022-04-01|     high pot  | 2022-08-01 | high pot return
bb        | 2022-04-03|     high pot  | 2022-08-04 | high pot return
```

A column with an identifier (distinct pseudonym) and pairwise data columns, date + text.
The data columns have an increasinig suffix. ..1 and ..2 belong togethter, etc.

From this a transformed long dataset is needed, where the pseudonym is not longer distinct.

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  Pseudonym = c("aa", "aa", "bb", "bb"),
  KE_date = c("2022-04-01", "2022-08-01", "2022-04-03", "2022-08-04"),
  KE_content = c("high pot", "high pot return", "high pot", "high pot return")
)
```

```
Pseudonym |  KE_date     |  KE_content
-------------------------------------------
aa        |  2022-04-01  |  high pot
aa        |  2022-08-01  |  high pot return
bb        |  2022-04-03  |  high pot
bb        |  2022-08-04  |  high pot return
```

Can anyone help?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `pivot_longer()` from `tidyr`.  You can specify the `names_pattern` argument to capture everything that comes before the underscore and digit at the end of the name.  This argument is a regular expression that identifies the unique names of the pivoted variables.  In the example below, I use `"(.*)_\\d$"`.  In regular expression terms, `.` matches any character.  The asterisk tells the regular expression to continue including characters until one doesn't match the search string.  For example, in the string `"aabbc"`, matching "a" would just identify the first character, but matching "a*" would match the first two characters.  Matching "." would again identify just the first character, but matching `".*"` would match all 5 characters.  In `names_pattern`, you put the pieces of information you want to extract in parentheses.  In the regular expression I used, everything before the underscore and digit at the end (the end of a string is marked with a dollar sign) , is captured, so from the variable names `"KE_content_1", "KE_date_2", "KE_content_3", "KE_date_4"`, the regular expression would return `"KE_content", "KE_date", "KE_content", "KE_date"`.   Then, using `names_to = ".value"` will put each of the unique values returned by the regular expression in `names_pattern` in a different column.  For more on how `pivot_longer()` works, you could look at the [pivoting vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/pivot.html) from the `tidyr` package.  For more information on regular expressions, you could google regex tutorial.  [This one](https://regexone.com) seems pretty good.

```r
input <- data.frame(
  Pseudonym = c("aa", "bb"),
  KE_date_1 = c("2022-04-01", "2022-04-03"),
  KE_content_2 = c("high pot", "high pot"),
  KE_date_3 = c("2022-08-01", "2022-08-04"),
  KE_content_4 = c("high pot return", "high pot return")
)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
input %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("KE"), 
               names_pattern="(.*)_\\d$", 
               names_to = ".value")
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   Pseudonym KE_date    KE_content     
#>   <chr>     <chr>      <chr>          
#> 1 aa        2022-04-01 high pot       
#> 2 aa        2022-08-01 high pot return
#> 3 bb        2022-04-03 high pot       
#> 4 bb        2022-08-04 high pot return
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I know the pivot_longer function, but I don't know what the parameter _names_pattern_ and __.value_ work. Could you please give a short explanation?

Comment: I added some explanation about how the arguments work.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. One last point: How I have to modify the regex if the column names are _KE_date1_ and _KE_content2_ without the second underscore?

Comment: `"(.*)\\d$"` should do it.

Comment: I understand :-) Could this extented to handle suffix numbers with different digits (_1, _12, _254)?

Comment: Sure, use `"(.*)_\\d*$"` to catch any number of digits after the underscore before the end of the string.